# How to make a citation reference-able?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I am using BibTex, and have created a citation: `\cite{referenceName}`. This produces a little number, e.g. `[1]`.

How do I make the `[1]` clickable, so that it references me to the location of the BibTex citation?

Comment: use the `hyperref` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with `\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}` and dig the other options.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
The reference is \cite{Pirayre_A_2015_j-bmc-bioinformatics_brane_cbrapnegcgrni}.
\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Pirayre_A_2015_j-bmc-bioinformatics_brane_cbrapnegcgrni}
A.~Pirayre, C.~Couprie, F.~Bidard, L.~Duval, and J.-C. Pesquet.
\newblock {BRANE} {C}ut: biologically-related a priori network enhancement with
  graph cuts for gene regulatory network inference.
\newblock {\em BMC Bioinformatics}, 16(1):369, Dec. 2015.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using a bibliography done by hand? And why do you have a `\bibliographystye` in there?

Comment: @Johannes_B I use .bib files, but included the content of the .bbl file to provide  a working example. Suggestions welcome

Comment: Use the `filecontents` package to create the .bib file on the fly at compiling time.